# Task with no status when Backfill DAG on Airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

The start_date for my DAG is:

```
'start_date': datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)-timedelta(hour=6, minutes=(datetime.now().minute % 30)),
```

and the command I give for backfill:

```
airflow backfill dag_id -s 2017-08-23T18:30:00 -e 2017-08-23T19:00:00
```

Now is a time in future (2017-08-23T22:00:00)

My DAG has two tasks (A and B) with A depends on B. 
Task A runs with success but task B remains with no status and in the UI in task details:

```
The execution date is 2017-08-23T18:30:00 but this is before the task's start date 2017-08-23T22:00:00.
```

Why start date is not the one specified with the cli command for backfill but the one in the DAG definition?

**EDIT 2017-08-28**

Backfill is for creating dag instances before the start_date of the dag.

```
airflow clear dag_id
```

should be used in order to clear the state of the dag in db and run again

Comment: We recommend against using dynamic values as start_date, especially datetime.now() as it can be quite confusing. The task is triggered once the period closes, and in theory an @hourly DAG would never get to an hour after now as now() moves along. airflow.incubator.apache.org/faq.html